# is there a faster way to give points for every one point other than to use hundreds of command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make it so when you buy something it will add a scoreboard counter... easy the hard part is I dont want to be placeing down hundreds of command blocks for one thing i want to add 2 counters for every one counter on a different scoreboard 1:2 can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what your problem is from what you've said but it seems like this command may help:

```
/scoreboard players set @p[r=3,score_(something)_min=(something),score_(something)=(something)] (your objective) (whatever you want)
```

This will let you change a players objective based on another objective they have.